# remove an Image programmatically in ezpublish

Tags: php, ezpublish

I have an Object in ezPublish which has an image attribute.
this attribute has an image as value that I want to remove it programmatically in PHP. ( the image value and not attribute itself )

any idea how to do it ?

Comment: Which ez publish version ?

Comment: ezpublish 4.7 (legacy)

Comment: Do you know how to update an attribute or is your question about updating any kind of attribute  ?

Comment: I know how to update an attribute and I even know how to update an image attribute. but I don't know how to remove that Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For versions of eZ Publish (Legacy) prior to Oct 15, 2013, or git tag, 'v2014.03.1' including eZ Publish 4.7 the 'deleteStoredObjectAttribute' method -**requires**- a non-null second argument value be passed in versions of eZ Publish Legacy before the following commit:

See: https://github.com/ezsystems/ezpublish-legacy/commit/61aaa002c00ccfb86b3e02856b319f54b3405ef8

This includes eZ Publish 4.7 and thus the question author's specific use case. Which is why this answer is more accurate than all others.

Without this second non-null parameter, the aliases image files would be deleted from the filesystem but ... the image aliases information (alias references, meta data, etc) would still exist with the content object attribute content (database storage xml).

Without the second non-parameter the image would appear as still partially existing in the content object but the image preview, (IE: usage of the image path, meta data by the system) would display a broken image and thus then represent a corrupt / incomplete copy of the original content object attribute content.

For maximum Backwards Compatibility, it's best to always pass a non-null second parameter since versions of eZ Publish Legacy beyond 10/15/2013 do not even use the second parameter in any way.

The following is a complete example of the source code required to remove a content object image attribute content (and remove the related meta-data and image file from disk) the best way possible for nearly any version of eZ Publish Legacy.

```
// The following two variables are filled with dummy values.
// You will need to change the contents of these variables to match
// your actual use case identifiers (Content Object ID / Class Attribute Identifier)
$objectID = 42;
$objectImageAttributeIdentifier = 'profile_image';

$object = eZContentObject::fetch( $objectID );

$objectID = $object->attribute( 'id' );
$objectCurrentVersion = $object->attribute( 'current_version' );
$objectDataMap = $object->attribute( 'data_map' );

if ( isset( $objectDataMap[ $objectImageAttributeIdentifier ] ) )
{
    $objectImageAttribute = $objectDataMap[ $objectImageAttributeIdentifier ];

    if ( $objectImageAttribute->attribute( 'has_content' ) )
    {
        $objectImageDataType = $objectImageAttribute->dataType();
        $objectImageDataType->deleteStoredObjectAttribute( $objectImageAttribute, $objectCurrentVersion );

        eZContentCacheManager::clearContentCacheIfNeeded( $objectID );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to `eZImageType::customObjectAttributeHTTPAction()`, you should use `eZImageType::deleteStoredObjectAttribute()`.

The method's implementation shows how it is done internally. The method won't delete the attribute itself, just the external data (image, aliases, set the xml to empty).

Comment: thanks Bertrand.
after running this method and updating the object with eZContentFunctions::updateAndPublishObject() , the image is removed from filesysem but in the ezadmin panel this is what I am getting: [link](http://s10.postimg.org/4b71493c9/Capture.jpg) 
and not correct

Comment: This would mean that one of the database records was not cleaned up correctly, either the xml in ezcontentobject_attribute, or the entry in ezimagefile.

Could you show the code you have used to do this ?